# What did Jesus mean when he said,"lead us not into temptation"?

Tags: matthew, jesus

I recently asked a question about free will.  When I did some research into [my question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/16788/does-isaiah-6317-suggest-that-humans-only-have-a-certain-amount-of-free-will), I discovered another text in the new testament regarding how a follower of Christ should pray. I am interested in the meaning of the first two verses, especially the first verse where it is written,

[Matthew:6:13 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%206:13)

> And lead us not into temptation,
>
> But deliver us from the evil one.

Jesus and his followers are sometimes depicted as a shepherd guiding his sheep, [with the sheep following the shepherd faithfully](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2010%3A27&version=NKJV;AMP;NIV;MSG). I am left wondering why the faithful sheep may be led into temptation by the shepherd.

What does it mean when Jesus asks his followers to pray to the father in Heaven that he will not "lead them into temptation"?

Comment: Is this different from [this](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1029/2873)?  Thanks.

Comment: @John Martin- Hi,probably be best for Susan to decide.They are similar.

Comment: @Bagpipes I have to agree w/ John Martin and say this is a dupe. Does the answer of the other question answer yours as well? If not, then you should re-phrase the question-Thanks!

Comment: I agree with all of the above. Bagpipes, you can revise to specify if your question isn’t answered by the answers on the duplicate; if so, this can still be re-opened.

Comment: @Bagpipes Although I'm sure Joseph could accomplish that, I'm not sure there's much point in somebody else changing the question just to make it not-a-dupe so that we re-open a question nobody really has, if that makes any sense. The only reason to edit/re-open in this situation would be if **you** read the other question/answers and see that the question you are wondering about is different in a way that wasn't clear in the original. I fully support requesting editing help in most circumstances, but do you see how it's not really productive here?

Comment: @Susan- Yes, i get your point! I have removed the comment.Your feed-back is appreciated.