(Exo 7:3-4)God's hardening of Pharoah's heart is akin to God stirring up negative emotions in a person but God Not controlling the actions of person

Exodus 7:3-4
New American Standard Bible 1995
3 But I will harden Pharaoh’s heart that I may multiply My signs and
My wonders in the land of Egypt. 4 When Pharaoh does not listen to
you, then I will lay My hand on Egypt and bring out My hosts, My
people the sons of Israel, from the land of Egypt by great judgments.

The following interpretation of Exodus 7:3-4  would be a counterargument that goes against Calvinist doctrines.
Could one just interpret God's hardening of Pharoah's heart as  akin to God merely stirring up negative emotions of anger, jealousy, discouragement, depression, stubbornness, etc., in a particular person but God Not controlling the  actions of said person?
To elaborate, God can stir up negative emotions of anger, jealousy, discouragement, depression, stubbornness, etc., in a particular person But it is said person's choice(Not God's choice) to behave in a manner reflecting on said emotions.
A good example is a parent who had a tough day at work, and returns home tired, frustrated and angry.
When said parent returns home, she/he finds her/his children being noisy and loud in a playful manner.
Said parent has a choice to either
politely tell said children to Not make so much noise, and subsequently explain to them that she/he is tired, frustrated and angry due to a tough day at work.
Or arrogantly yell and shout at said children to be quiet
The negative emotions that God might merely stir up in a person are just emotions that said person will have to tactfully handle, but Rarely will be correct or valid for said person to  behave in a manner reflecting on said emotions
Therefore, in Exodus 7:3-4, hardening of Pharoah's heart by God are merely a matter of God stirring up negative emotions in the Pharoah, but it was Pharoah's own choice to behave in a manner reflecting on said emotions
Would the aforementioned interpretation be valid and correct?  Please elaborate in your response as to why or why not.

Does this answer your question?
https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47784/exodus-912-how-is-it-accepted-that-the-lord-hardens-the-heart-of-pharaoh-then/47792#47792

@PerryWebb +1 for bringing up the example of how a police sting operation can be similar to God's hardening of Pharoah's heart

When humanity move forward, the Lord may choose to intervene in history or let events unfold. As the Lord of history, He can steer its course according to His will. The Lord informed Abraham in advance about the Exodus. In Genesis 15:13-14, the Lord said to Abraham:

13 Then the Lord said to him, “Know for certain that for four hundred years your descendants will be strangers in a country not their own and that they will be enslaved and mistreated there. 14 But I will punish the nation they serve as slaves, and afterward they will come out with great possessions. (NIV)

To understand whether the Lord needed to harden Pharoah's heart to accomplish His plan, we must consider this question: "If the Lord had done nothing, would Pharoah have immediately released the Israelites at Moses' request?" Given that the Israelites were a significant labor resources for the Egyptians, the answer is likely "NO".
The next question is: Given that Pharoah's heart was naturally hardened against releasing the Israelites. "Did the Lord need to further provoke his negative emotions?" Pharoah seemed to soften his heart during the 3rd plague (Exo 8:8); the 5th plague (Exo 8:28); the 8th plague (Exo 9:27-28) and the 9th plague (Exo 10:16-17). Each time, he appeared progressively more remorseful for his wrongdoings against the Lord. However, once his troubles relieved, his heart hardened again.

Pharaoh summoned Moses and Aaron and said, “Pray to the Lord to take the frogs away from me and my people, and I will let your people go to offer sacrifices to the Lord.” (Exo 8:8 NIV)


Pharaoh said, “I will let you go to offer sacrifices to the Lord your God in the wilderness, but you must not go very far. Now pray for me.” (Exo 8:28 NIV)


27 Then Pharaoh summoned Moses and Aaron. “This time I have sinned,” he said to them. “The Lord is in the right, and I and my people are in the wrong. 28 Pray to the Lord, for we have had enough thunder and hail. I will let you go; you don’t have to stay any longer.” (Exo 9:27-28 NIV)


16 Pharaoh quickly summoned Moses and Aaron and said, “I have sinned against the Lord your God and against you. 17 Now forgive my sin once more and pray to the Lord your God to take this deadly plague away from me.” (Exo 10:16-17 NIV)

Why did the Lord not skip straight to the tenth plague - the death of the firstborn - instead of staging ten plagues to punish the Egyptians and save His people? A closer analysis of Pharoah's responses to the plague reveals a common mentality when people facing troubles: denial, wishful thinking, emotional conflict, and anger.
The Lord didn't need to provoke negative emotions in Pharoah because He knew that unresolved troubles would naturally lead to a progressive development of these emotions, utimately culminating in total collapse. This is a hard-learned lesson, not just for Pharoah, but a reminder to us all.

But God "does provoke negative emtions in Pharoah" as it explicitly mentions in (Exodus 9:12) (NASB1995)
"And the Lord hardened Pharaoh’s heart, and he did not listen to them, just as the Lord had spoken to Moses."    One of the major lessons that the bible reader can learn from Pharoah is to Never give into selfish personal stubborn emotions.

@user1338998- Let's address the statement "the Lord hardened Pharaoh's heart". Pharaoh's heart was already hardened. The Lord could have softened it by changing his heart or hardened it further by pushing Pharaoh's already hardened heart to its limit until he collapsed. Clearly, the Lord chose the latter. The statement is valid only if Pharaoh softened his heart during one of the plagues but the Lord hardened it again to make him retract his words to Moses. Since Pharaoh sent his army to pursue the Israelites, his heart must have remained hardened even after the 10th plague and never softened
